# image-dired: Change thickness of cursor

Tags: dired, faces, images, style, image-dired

On a hires screen I find it really hard to see on which image the cursor currently is, because the rectangle around the image is very thin. *Is it possible to increase the line width of that rectangle?*

Already I looked through customization options, through `image-dired.el`, and using `what-cursor-position` I inspected what’s at on cursor position, all to no avail.

[image: Screenshot showing example]

Answer (score 1):

You might try customizing one or both of these image-dired options (the text is what you get with `C-h v`).

- **`image-dired-thumb-relief`** - Size of button-like border around thumbnails.
- **`image-dired-thumb-margin`** - Size of the margin around thumbnails. This is where you see the cursor.

There are many other image-dired options, some of which might also help you more easily see which choice is currently selected.  Use `M-x customize-group RET image-dired RET` to see them all.

Comment: As I wrote, “already I looked through customization options”. The two options you mentioned don’t change the line thickness of the rectangle indicating the current cursor position.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how you might fatten the box's line width. But does either of them reduce your problem: *"I find it really hard to see on which image the cursor currently is"*? If you don't find a good answer for fattening the line width, does either of these options at least help you see which image is selected?

Comment: The line is just very thin, hard to see. The options I knew before, and they are already customized as can be seen in the screenshot I posted as part of my question.

Comment: The question is how the box is generated. Once that is known, the line thickness can hopefully be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @feklee that this is a major problem for those who use Image-Dired. Finding the selected icon is like looking for a needle in a haystack. The solution provided by @Drew helps. My pragmatic solution is to hit RET and then DEL as I look for the thumbnail. The movement allows my eyes to find the right image.